# How to copy and paste values in a row based on table input and paste them into a dynamic Worksheet name

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2016

I have a workbook with two sheets. The "Companies" Worksheet has a dynamic rows and with set columns A - J.

In Worksheet "Table - Summary" I have a summary of the unique company names and I have used a code to get the unique names from column b in the "Companies" Worksheet. In the "Table Summary" sheet is where people get assign to the unique companies and sheets are distributed according to which companies an individual has been assign to. Which the name of the individual is entered in column 3 in the "Table - Summary" Sheet.

I have some code where it creates a worksheet according to what was enter in the "Table - Summary" sheet in cells(LastRow, 3). There are more than 10 individuals that are assign to several companies which varies depending what name the assigner inputs in column C. Please see picture. I don't want to create duplicate worksheets for each assignee. I did a google search for suggestions, such as a function were it checks if the worksheet exists but had no clue what it was doing. If I could get assistance with this too. Please and thank you.

How can I tell VBA to check through columns b in the "Table - Summary" sheet to copy and paste the rows that have the customer names in column b of the "companies" sheet. And place it into the corresponding worksheet of the assignee.

I'm very new to VBA. If I was unclear. P Lease let me know

[image]

[image]

[image]

```
Sub GetAssignedCompanies()
    Dim wbMaster As Workbook
    Dim shI As Worksheet
    Dim shS As Worksheet

    Set wbMaster = Workbooks("Workbook1.xlsx")
    Set shI = wbMaster.Worksheets("Companies")
    Set shS = wbMaster.Worksheets("Table - Summary")

    Dim LastRow As Integer
    Dim EndRow As Integer
    Dim aName As String

    LastRow = 4
    EndRow = 2
    While Len(shS.Cells(LastRow, 2).Value) > 0
        aName = shS.Cells(LastRow, 3).Value

        If Not aName = vbNullString Then
            Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.count)).Name = aName
        End If

        LastRow = LastRow + 1
    Wend
End Sub
```

Comment: So all you want to do is put the company name in a worksheet with the Individual's Name that was assigned to the company account in Worksheets("Table - Summary"). Is the company name the same in both worksheets "Companies" and "Table - Summary"? Where do you want to paste the company names in each individuals worksheet? All this can be done easily by filtering "Table - Summary" column 2 for each individuals name and copying the visible cells in column1, then pasting to the individuals worksheet.

Comment: Are the company names the same in both worksheets? What range do you need copied from worksheets "Companies" to the employee's worksheet? what Range on the employee's worksheet do you want to paste the copied range?

Comment: In the "companies" worksheet there is a range from range "A1:J" & LastRow. The company names are spelled the same. In the "Companies" sheet the companies name are column b. In the "Table - Summary" sheet the companies name are in column b.  The image above represents the "Table - Summary" sheet. So I want the macro to run on the "Table - Summary" and look at column C where the name of the assignee is found. I would like to create a worksheet with the name of the assignee.

Comment: Then paste the rows of the company. which the macro will be looking at column b of the "companies" sheet to see if the companie name is there . If true then copy the whole row to the individual worksheet,  which they were assign to that company in the "Table - Summary".

Comment: See my edit in the answer.

Comment: Your code does somewhat I'm looking for but instead I want to copy the rows in the shI or the companies sheet. Not the values in the Summary Sheet. The summary sheet is for the macro to see who was assign to which company and then extract the rows from the companies sheet with the company value in column B. Please see attached

Comment: attached worksheet

Comment: Wait I dont know how to attach a worksheet but I took screenshots with new example.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example; You need to create the new worksheets for each employee before you Run this macro; It will write the company names from "Table - Summary" column 1, into column 1 of the employee's worksheet. Change the names of your employee worksheets as needed.

```
'You need to create the individual worksheet before running this macro.
Dim nameShtArr, i As Long, shS As Worksheet, shI As Worksheet

Set shI = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Companies")
Set shS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Summary")

nameShtArr = Array("Tom", "Bob", "Joe")

    For i = LBound(nameShtArr) To UBound(nameShtArr)
        With shS.Range("C2:C" & Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row)
            .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=nameShtArr(i)
        End With

        'Place the company names assigned to the employee in column A.
        shS.Range("B2:B20").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Worksheets(nameShtArr(i)).Range("A1")

        'This next section will loop through each company name in the current worksheet and find it in ColB,
        'if it finds the company name it will copy the data in the row to ColJ and paste it into the current worksheet.
        Dim lRow As Long
        lRow = Worksheets(nameShtArr(i)).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

            For Each Cel In Sheets(nameShtArr(i)).Range("A1:A" & lRow)
                Dim fndCel As Range
                Set fndCel = shI.Range("B:B").Find(Cel.Value)
                    If Not fndCel Is Nothing Then
                        fndCel.Offset(, 1).Resize(, 10).Copy Cel.Offset(, 1)
                    End If
            Next Cel
    Next i

    shS.Cells.AutoFilter
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your response. The "Table - Summary" Sheet its just an overview for the Assigner to say okay this person is going to be assign to this "company". It is used as a reference sheet for the assigner since they want to look up and say oh yeah I assigned this company to this individual. I want the macro to look at the input in the "Table - Summary " sheet. See below for image. And the assignee to get the values of the rows that are in the "companies" sheet. The companies sheet is the source. Because it has the name of the companies in column b.

Comment: If it finds the company name, which is in column 2 of the "Table - Summary" in column b of the "companies sheet then copy and paste value into the assignee worksheet.